# Angular ng object in production bundles in Cypress

Tags: angular, cypress, developer-tools

I was writing a Cypress testing for a Angular application which has a canvas element inside it (a chart.js object). So as I cannot inspect canvas element to check it's content, I decided to grab angular component and just check if the method that generated data to build the chart was being called. So that's the moment my problems began. I'll try to describe it in an easy way.

When you are running an Angular application in **development mode**, you can open the console in chrome developer tools and access the `window.ng` object:

[image]

However, the `ng` object doesn't exist if you compile to **production**:

[image]

Is there any way to get access to ng in a production build?

At first, I thought it was a matter of generating the `.map` files, but it wasn't enough to solve the problem though.

Is there anything I could do? In my real use case, I'd need that so I could get access to an Angular component method contained in a Cypress test.

UPDATE: I'm using Angular 9.0.0-rc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, because you're asking for debugging help. If the `ng` var is missing, then you should report this as a bug and it looks like you're using Angular 9 (which would have been helpful to know in the question).

Comment: Yeah, I'm using angular 9. Out of curiosity: how do you know I'm using this version? Is this a known issue with Ivy? I'll add the version information to the question and I hope it doesn't get closed because I really don't know any other forum that could be a better place to ask this (of course, if this is really a bug, angular repo would be the right place - I'll ask this at the repo.)

Comment: @Reactgular, this isn't a debug question. The problem is that I need this `ng` object so I can access a component in a Cypress test. So I think it's more like a testing question (which is a programming one).

Comment: I can see in the autocomplete new methods only found in Angular 9. I'm not sure there is much anyone here can do to fix this for you. You can wait and see if someone answers it, but this variable has been around for many versions. If it's missing, then that's very strange and most likely an Angular 9 thing. I would check to see if it get renamed by minification.

Comment: @Reactgular, I've open an issue at angular repo and it was labeled as a bug. If it's confirmed as a bug, I'll close this one.

Comment: Can you add a link to the issue in the comments here so that others will find it.

Comment: It's apparently a bug related to Ivy: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34458